# Requiero resolver MD5 en este login

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando que este código interprete md5 desde una bd en MySql, gracias por su aporte,  en esta forma de resuelve error 500

```
 <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    
        require 'conn/connection.php';
    
        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
        $password = md5($password);   /*<======ya intente aqui*/
    
    
    
    
        $users = $conn->prepare("select username, password, rol from users where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'");
        $users->execute();
        if($users->rowCount() > 0){
            $user = $users->fetch();
            if($user['username'] == $username && $user['password'] == $password){
                //existe el usuario y esa contrase;a
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                $_SESSION["rol"] = $user['rol'];
                setcookie("activo", 1, time() + 3600);
                header("Location: inicio.view.php", true, 301);
            } else {
                http_response_code(401);
                //echo "Credenciales incorrectas";
                header('location:index.php?err=1');
            }
        }else {
            http_response_code(401);
            header('location:index.php?err=1');
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(405);
        echo "SOLO SE PUEDE POST";
    
        // POST_GET
    }
```

Comment: Mi recomendacion personal es que no uses el hashing md5 para proteger claves, ya que no son seguros y en la actualidad puede romperse con relativa facilidad, investiga sobre otros algoritmos de hash tales como SHA-3

Comment: Si fuera ese el caso como editaria código para el so sha-3

Comment: Si en tu consulta ya filtras por user y pass, entonces solo debería devolverte un único registro, que sería el usuario...

Comment: No te pido que cambies el código sino que investigues sobre otros algoritmos hash mucho más seguros y robustos que el que usas, el cual hace vulnerable a tu aplicación

Comment: gracias, veo que el problema solo es el localhost por que en  las nube funciona bien. Buscare documentarme mas en otros algoritmos .